# CQL TypeError: Received an argument of invalid type for column

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, cql

I am using `Cassandra Python driver`, and I created a table, in the table there is a column (called date) defined as `timestamp`. I tried to access values from a dataframe and insert rows into the table using these values. The dataframe value corresponding to date has the format (captured from `PyCharm` debug mode),

`Timestamp('2006-09-29 00:00:00')`

But I got the following error,

```
TypeError: Received an argument of invalid type for column "date". Expected: <class 'cassandra.cqltypes.DateType'>, Got: <class 'str'>; (DateType arguments must be a datetime, date, or timestamp)
```

The table is defined as,

```
CREATE TABLE test_keyspace.test_table (
key1 text PRIMARY KEY,
key2 float,
key3 text,
key4 text,
key5 text,
date timestamp
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

UPDATE

The problem is due to there are NaTs in the dataframe and forgot to remove them before insert them into cassandra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `datetime.datetime(2016,09,29)` instead

Comment: I also used `pandas.to_datetime()` with `format` parameter specified in the dataframe before using `Cassandra` to insert rows into the table, so `pandas datetime` doesn't compatible with `Cassandra Timestamp`?

Comment: Hmmm. I would think pandas.to_datetime() would work since it returns a datetime.datetime object. Not sure why it doesn't.

Comment: datetime.datetime(2016,9,29) instead of using 09